# Scraping Headlines off of Yahoo! Finance with Python3

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape the headlines off of Yahoo! Finance's page for individual stocks. For example, I wanted to get the headlines for GOOGL, but I can't seem to get the right CSS selector for BeautifulSoup to scrape. Any ideas? I have tried multiple variations of the code below and substituting my selector with: "a", "href", "#yui_3_9_1_8_1459741486422_44", "li", "ul" etc. I've left my latest iteration with the "a" tag which, I know, gives you all the page's links, not simply the headlines.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GOOGL'
res = requests.get(URL)
res.raise_for_status()
content = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select('a'))
```

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=GOOGL&t=2016-04-03T21:02:10-04:00

This is what I get when I try to copy the selector (I have Chrome, utilizing the built-in Inspector): #yui_3_9_1_8_1459741486422_44. Tried every variation I could think of for this id, nothing has worked.

The API, ystockquote, doesn't have a function which lets you easily get the headlines, I don't think...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the list of headline links from under the `div` with `yfi_quote_headline` class:

```
links = soup.select('div.yfi_quote_headline ul > li > a')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. Two follow-up questions: 1) how can you tell that the headline is contained in that div? And 2) how would I then go about getting the actual hyperlink?

Comment: @Harel please make sure the headline articles are the same as you see in the browser - I am still not sure this would get you the complete and accurate headlines. Actual hyperlink is available via `link["href"]`.